# Plot Price Value

Tags: pine-script

Afternoon,

I would like to include the price of previous day EQ into my plotshape.

I don't think this is possible, or is it?

Do I need to use labels?

```
plot(pdEQ, "pdEQ", change(pdEQ) ? na : color.orange, offset = 0)
plotshape(pdEQ, style=shape.labeldown, location=location.absolute, color=color.orange,  textcolor=color.white, show_last=1, text="pdEQ",  offset = offset_val, transp=20, title="pdEQ")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct. This is not possible with `plotshape()`.
The `text` parameter must be a `const string`, so you cannot use a mutable variable for that.
You'll need to use labels.